Gray frames appear sometimes when chapters change in trans coding of 4k Blu-ray
This is not happening with every 4k movie, but it is happening with most. The audio is still working when the video goes gray. The command template I am using is
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i "{movieLocation}" -vf scale_qsv=format=nv12:format=nv12 -c:v h264_qsv -crf 23 -c:a aac "{destination}/{fileNumber} - {movieName}.{fileExtension}"

I have attached a video so you can see what I am talking about. Those gray frames last for the entire chapter.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/151Uxk75GLz5RaSPfHFTzTGiUzt42VetB/view?usp=sharing

I have ran some testing and the same problem does not appear without hardware acceleration.

I just tested it on Linux using Jellyfin's version of FFmpeg and I did not get the problem! I am going to try and reinstall FFmpeg and if that doesn't work I might just use Jellyfin's FFmpeg.

I switched to using Jellyfin's version of FFmpeg
